# Adding integers to arraylist "scores"

Tags: java

I have a text file with about 5000 names or so, each separated by line.

I am have already accomplished adding all the names to an ArrayList "names", but
i am not able to add anything to my arrayList scores.

I don't know where I'm going wrong, especially in the addScores method, nothing gets outputted at all.

If anymore information is required, please ask.

And thanks for the help..

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class ScoringNames {
    BufferedReader x = null;
    String location = "xxxxx\\names.txt";

    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Integer> scores = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public void readFile(){ //Opens file, and prints every line.
        try{
            x = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(location));
        } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try{
            String name = x.readLine();
            while(name != null){
                //System.out.println(name);
                names.add(name);
                name = x.readLine();
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public int nameScore(String name){
        this.readFile();  //Open file and read, so that values are added to <names>
        this.sortNames();
        int score = 0;
        char[] tempName = name.toCharArray();
        for (char i : tempName){
                score += alphValue(i);
            }

        return score;
    }

    public void addScores(){
        for(String x : names){
            scores.add(nameScore(x));
        }
    }

    public void printScores(){
        for(int counter: scores)
            System.out.println(counter);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ScoringNames abc = new ScoringNames();
        abc.readFile();

        abc.addScores();
        abc.printScores();




    }

}
```

The error i get is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:901)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:851)
    at ScoringNames.addScores(ScoringNames.java:148)
    at ScoringNames.main(ScoringNames.java:163)
```

Comment: Could you remove all the irrelevant code?

Comment: What do you mean "i am not able to add anything to my arrayList scores"?  Are you getting an error, or does the list stay empty?

Comment: Instead of those 100 lines of switch/case you could just use `"AB....Z".indexOf(x) + 1"`

Comment: @SteveSmith before, i would get an empty list. now i get an error in for(String x : names)

Comment: What Error you are getting?

Comment: I would always suggest avoiding mutable state when possible, since it's so easy to get the ordering wrong (and much harder to reason about).  For example, instead of `void addScores()` which both reads from and writes to fields, you could declare it as `List<Integer> addScores(List<String> names)`, passing in the arguments needed and returning the resulting scores.

Comment: Or also `x - 'A' + 1`.

Comment: In your addScores method you call the nameScore method for every String in the List names. But in the nameScore method you call readFile again which will again add all names to your names List. So for every name you try to get the scores for you add all names to your namesList again. This should totally blow up unless i'm mistaken.

Comment: Why can't you show us the error?

Comment: @SteveSmith added in main post.

Comment: Im sorry guys i wont be available to answer questions for about 2 hours, but thanks for theongoing help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are modifying the `List` `names` while accessing it from the `For` loop of `addScores()` method.

When you call `nameScore(String str)` method, Then you don't need to read the file again as all data has been read already and stored in the `names` list. You need to do just evaluation of the `String` and return the score.

```
public int nameScore(String name){
    int score = 0;
    char[] tempName = name.toCharArray();
    for (char i : tempName){
            score += alphValue(i);
        }

    return score;
}
```

Comment: Where Can I add those two then?

Comment: You don't need to add them because you have already executed both of them in main function. Actually calling both of the functions multiple times may create a problem for the `List` because It keeps on adding the values of File every time you call it. So you will be having `duplication` of data in your `List` which may create a problem for you.

Comment: Hmm. Will check full functionality when I can return to computer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Change method `nameScore` - remove two top lines.

```
    this.readFile(); // Open file and read, so that values are added to
                        // <names>
    this.sortNames();
```

There are not unnecessary and the `readFile()` is the reason of the error.
The reason of the error is that you try to change `this.names` value in for each loop (`for (String x : names)`) and that is forbidden in Java.

```
public int nameScore(String name) {
    int score = 0;
    char[] tempName = name.toCharArray();
    for (char i : tempName) {
        score += alphValue(i);
    }

    return score;
}
```